# How do I get the position of the element in a listview that started a dialog

Tags: android, listview, dialog

I got a listview and the elements in this listview can trigger a contextmenu.
After that i can get the position of the element which triggered the contextmenu. (this works)

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo); 
        MenuInflater m = getMenuInflater();  

        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.listview: m.inflate(R.menu.series_contextmenu, menu); 
                                break;
            default: break;
        }
    }
```

In this context menu I start a dialog. But when I start the dialog I don't know how I get the position of the element in the listview which started the dialog.

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {  
        int position = 0;
        AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();  
        position = (int) info.id;

        switch(item.getItemId()){  
             case R.id.deleteSeries:  
                  seriesList.remove(position);
                  listviewadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                  return true;
             case R.id.changeSeriesName: showDialog(CHANGE_SERIESNAME_DIALOG);
                                     // cannot continue here after dialog.dismiss()
                                         return true;
        }           
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);  
   }
```

After I close the dialog I want to change the name of the element in thelistView. I can get the text from the (EditText) element but I don't know where to continue after the dialog closes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the position in a variable somewhere, either at the Activity level or inside of the dialog (using a custom dialog).  Then use that variable when dismiss is called.

Comment: I got the same idea (but where do I continue in my code after the dialog closes)?

Comment: You set a onDismissListener via setOnDismissListener().